# React input radio won't update checked

Tags: reactjs, forms, state

## My problem:

I'm trying to make a simple radio with two options, when I set the state of the field the checked value should update but it doesn't.
The condition used in checked inside the input seems to be ok but the inputs won't alternate

## My code:

```
import { FormEvent, useState } from "react"

function CadastroGeral(){

    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        Tipo: "Comércio",
        RazaoSocial: "",
        NomeFantasia: ""
    })

    function handleSubmit(event: FormEvent){
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log(form)
    }

    async function handleChangeTipo(event: any){
        await setForm(oldForm => {
            oldForm.Tipo = event.target.value
            return oldForm
        })
        console.log(form) //the data comes out updated
    }

    //other handlers here, all of them work just fine

    return(
        <div className="wrapper-page">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="content-container form-agendamento">
                <div className="w-10 form-group">
                    <h1>Selecione seu tipo</h1>
                    <span>
                        <input type="radio" value="Comércio" checked={form.Tipo === 'Comércio'} onChange={handleChangeTipo}/>
                        Comércio
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <input type="radio" value="Indústria" checked={form.Tipo === 'Indústria'} onChange={handleChangeTipo}/>
                        Indústria
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div className="w-10">
                    <input type="text" className="w-5" placeholder="Razão Social" onChange={handleChangeRazaoSocial}/>
                    <input type="text" className="w-5" placeholder="Nome Fantasia" onChange={handleChangeNomeFantasia}/>
                </div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                    Enviar
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CadastroGeral
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` need to return new value like this

```
setForm((oldForm) => {
  return { ...oldForm, Tipo: event.target.value };
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you explain what the "..." means or send a link?

Comment: It is spread operators. You can see detail in here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax